# Kivy get TextInput from Popup

Tags: python, kivy

I have a simple app that asks for your name and age in a `TextInput` field.
When you click the save button a `Popup` opens and you can save the name and age from the `TextInput` in a file.

Question: 
How can I access the Name and Age when the `Popup` is already open?
Right now I store the `TextInput` data in a dictionary before I open the `Popup`.
This workaround does work, but there most certainly is a more elegant solution than this:

```
class SaveDialog(Popup):
    def redirect(self, path, filename):
        RootWidget().saveJson(path, filename)
    def cancel(self):
        self.dismiss()

class RootWidget(Widget):
    data = {}

    def show_save(self):
        self.data['name'] = self.ids.text_name.text
        self.data['age'] = self.ids.text_age.text
        SaveDialog().open()

    def saveFile(self, path, filename):
        with open(path + '/' + filename, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(self.data, f)
        SaveDialog().cancel()
```

Answer (score 3):

Yoy can pass your object to the popup object. That way you can accsess all the widgets attributes for the popup object.
An example of this can look like this.

```
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.app import App


class MyWidget(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyWidget,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.orientation = "vertical"

        self.name_input = TextInput(text='name')

        self.add_widget(self.name_input)

        self.save_button = Button(text="Save")
        self.save_button.bind(on_press=self.save)

        self.save_popup = SaveDialog(self) # initiation of the popup, and self gets passed

        self.add_widget(self.save_button)


    def save(self,*args):
        self.save_popup.open()


class SaveDialog(Popup):

    def __init__(self,my_widget,**kwargs):  # my_widget is now the object where popup was called from.
        super(SaveDialog,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.my_widget = my_widget

        self.content = BoxLayout(orientation="horizontal")

        self.save_button = Button(text='Save')
        self.save_button.bind(on_press=self.save)

        self.cancel_button = Button(text='Cancel')
        self.cancel_button.bind(on_press=self.cancel)

        self.content.add_widget(self.save_button)
        self.content.add_widget(self.cancel_button)

    def save(self,*args):
        print "save %s" % self.my_widget.name_input.text # and you can access all of its attributes
        #do some save stuff
        self.dismiss()

    def cancel(self,*args):
        print "cancel"
        self.dismiss()


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it backwards get the data from the popup and access it in the main app ?

Comment: @user2067030 yes in the main widget class, `self.save_popup` is the popup object. So you can access its data by calling its attributes `self.save_popup.whatever_data_you_save_in_there`